# Hydraulic jack and pascal's law

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, applied-physics

When using the hyraulic jack , I am totally convinced that the pressure at the initial phase must be the same in the interconnecting liquid and both surfaces where force is applied (pascal's law) , But the question is about the end state , as long as one area surface will move downward and the other is upward , so there will be difference in height .. therefore there is delta p :

Delta p = density . g . Delta h

This is mathimatically , but physically i  still somehow FEEL it must be the same pressure ..

So is it the same , or different , and why?! And am I understanding the pascal's law correctly!

Answer (score 2):

With a hydraulic jack, the weight of the object being lifted is usually much greater than the weight of the working liquid. Therefore the difference in pressure in the working liquid due to different heights will be much smaller than its absolute pressure, and may be difficult to measure.

To expand my answer, in a hydraulic jack you apply a relatively small force $F_1$ to a small surfaces area $A_1$ which produces a larger force $F_2$ on a larger surface area $A_2$. The relationship is usually stated as

$\displaystyle \frac {F_1}{A_1} = \frac {F_2}{A_2}$

but this assume the surfaces are at the same height. If the second surface is at a height $h$ above the first surface then the correct relationship is

$\displaystyle \frac {F_1}{A_1} = \frac {F_2+W}{A_2}$

where $W$ is the weight of the working fluid in a column of area $A_2$ and height $h$. Since $W= \rho A_2 g h$ we get

$\displaystyle \frac {F_1}{A_1} = \frac {F_2}{A_2}+ \rho g h$

but usually the correcting term $\rho g h$ is small compared with the other pressure terms.

Comment: Appreciated ur answer! But why is there this difference while the pressure is equally distributed .. it is contradictory!!!

Comment: @noor1 I’m not sure where you think the contradiction is. Pascal’s Law does not say that the pressure is the same at all heights in a body of liquid - we know this is not true - it only says that a *change* in pressure is transmitted through the whole body of liquid.

Comment: The thing is that as u said "the increase is the same in all parts " and firstly the two areas has the same pressure p2 .so if the increase is the same they must also have the same pressure p2>p1. But this is not the case !! P2 of area 1 is not equal to p2 of area 2 ..

Comment: @noor1 I have expanded my answer. If this is still not clear you may need to ask another more specific question.

Comment: Oh yeah its clear!! but still one question , let us assume that the surfaces were initially at the same level , then pressure is applied and distributed evenly -according to pascal law- and the increase in pressure in all the points is the same  - assuming pt A is on the small area surface and pt B is on the other-that means the pressure at A = P0 + delta P , P0=initial pressure , and must be equal to pressure at point B!!! But it is not hte case .. point B is eventually at higher altitude with greater pressure Pb=Pa+ row.g.h!!

Answer (score 2):

A jack with hydraulic oil in it will have a very slight pressure difference from the top to the bottom due to pressure increasing with depth. This is negligible to the operation of the jack. For instance, a typical hydraulic jack with a load on it may have around 1800 psi at the top of the cylinder, and around 1800.4 psi at the bottom, depending on its height. Some hydraulic jacks are made to operate horizontally so the pump height and pressure could be nearly the same as the head height and pressure.